# Deleting or replacing inner elements depending on higher level elements

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, data-structures

Consider a data structure like:

```
data = {{"experiment"->1, "tags"->{"type"->1}, "results"->{{"x", 2}, {"y", 5}, {"z", 5}}},
        {"experiment"->2, "tags"->{"type"->2}, "results"->{{"x", 1}, {"y", 2}}},
        {"experiment"->3, "tags"->{"type"->1}, "results"->{{"y", 2}, {"x", 1}, {"z", 6}, {"w", 3}}}}
```

I would like to delete "y" results from type 1 experiments. So I want to obtain this output:

```
{{"experiment"->1, "tags"->{"type"->1}, "results"->{{"x", 2}, {"z", 5}}},
 {"experiment"->2, "tags"->{"type"->2}, "results"->{{"x", 1}, {"y", 2}}},
 {"experiment"->3, "tags"->{"type"->1}, "results"->{{"x", 1}, {"z", 6}, {"w", 3}}}}
```

This can probably be done in an easier way by using associations, but I can't use them before the new CDF Player 10 is available.

This is the solution that I have found:

```
data /. {before : ___, 
         "tags" -> tags : ({___, "type" -> 1, ___}),
         middle : ___,
         "results" -> results : {___, {"y", _}, ___},
         after : ___} :> {before, tags, middle,
                          "results" -> DeleteCases[results, {"y", _}],
                          after}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

**UPDATE**: I was to adapt Leonid answer to this:

```
Replace[
  data,
  row_ /; ("type" /. ("tags" /. row)) == 1 :>
    Replace[
      row,
      HoldPattern["results" -> _] :>
        Rule["results", DeleteCases["results" /. row, {"y", _}]], 
      {1}],
  {1}
]
```

I'll now study Michael's answer. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will work regardless of how `tags` and `results` are ordered:

```
Replace[data,
  experiment : {___, "tags" -> {___, "type" -> 1, ___}, ___} :>
    Replace[experiment, 
      ("results" -> {before___, {"y", _}, after___}) :>
        ("results" -> {before, after}), 
      {1}],
  {1}]
```

Comment: This is a modification of the answer in my updated question. And I like it. It is easier to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid associations, you could create a database-type function of your own:

```
ClearAll[entry];
entry[e___][property_String] := property /. {e};
entry[e___][{properties__String}] := Fold[ReplaceAll[#2, #1] &, {e}, {properties}];
Set[entry[e___][property_String], val_] ^:= entry[e] /. (property -> _) :> property -> val;

entry @@@ data /.
  e_entry /; e[{"tags", "type"}] == 1 :>
    (e["results"] = DeleteCases[e["results"], {"y", _}]) /. entry -> List
(*
  {{"experiment" -> 1, "tags" -> {"type" -> 1}, "results" -> {{"x", 2}, {"z", 5}}},
   {"experiment" -> 2, "tags" -> {"type" -> 2}, "results" -> {{"x", 1}, {"y", 2}}},
   {"experiment" -> 3, "tags" -> {"type" -> 1}, "results" -> {{"x", 1}, {"z", 6}, {"w", 3}}}}
*)
```

More succinct adaptation of OP's, though it assumes `"type"` appears in only `"tags"`:

```
Replace[data,
 entry_ /; !FreeQ[entry, "type" -> 1] :> (entry /. {"y", _} -> Sequence[]),
 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I came to a bit shorter version of your updated code:

```
Replace[data, a_ /; ("type" /. ("tags" /. a)) == 1 :>
    (a /. ("results" -> b_) :> "results" -> DeleteCases[b, {"y", _}]), 1]

(* 
{{"experiment" -> 1, "tags" -> {"type" -> 1}, "results" -> {{"x", 2}, {"z", 5}}}, 
 {"experiment" -> 2, "tags" -> {"type" -> 2}, "results" -> {{"x", 1}, {"y", 2}}}, 
 {"experiment" -> 3, "tags" -> {"type" -> 1}, "results" -> {{"x", 1}, {"z", 6}, {"w", 3}}}}
*)
```

You can see that `HoldPattern` and some brackets are not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for this. By removing the second Replace command it became more powerful for my actual application.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if this is better than what you have (I have to confess I don't fully understand the syntax you use), but it certainly is a direct and easy-to-understand method.

```
data = {{"experiment"->1, "tags"->{"type"->1}, "results"->{{"x", 2}, {"y", 5}, {"z", 5}}},
    {"experiment"->2, "tags"->{"type"->2}, "results"->{{"x", 1}, {"y", 2}}},
    {"experiment"->3, "tags"->{"type"->1}, "results"->{{"y", 2}, {"x", 1}, {"z", 6}, {"w", 3}}}}
```

First figure out where in the data you have a "y"

```
ypositions = Position[data, "y"]
(*Out[2]={{1, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 1, 1}}*)
```

Then keep only the "y" positions that correspond to a type 1 data tag,

```
ypositions = Select[ypositions, (data[[#[[1]], 2, 2, 1, 2]] == 1) &]
```

Then remove from data all those elements, going up one level.

```
data=Delete[data, ypositions[[All, ;; -2]]]

(*Out[3]=     {{"experiment"->1, "tags"->{"type"->1}, "results"->{{"x", 2}, {"z", 5}}},
               {"experiment"->2, "tags"->{"type"->2}, "results"->{{"x", 1}, {"y", 2}}},
               {"experiment"->3, "tags"->{"type"->1}, "results"->{{"x", 1}, {"z", 6}, {"w", 3}}}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this solution is that it deletes the "y" result for experiment 2 which is not of type 1.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino, D'oh!  Sorry about that.  Now it works, but it is more clunky and less versatile. That is, if you change where in the structure the "type" tag is stored it will not work any more.